# Loader Class View Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In the codeigniter systems core loader.php there is a $`this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH.'views/'   => TRUE);` function

If I wanted to change path to `$this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH.'views/template'=> TRUE);`function.

Would I be able to do it in the MY_Loader.php Will it overwrite the default location.

I have hmvc but not changing view path

```
public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
        list($path, $_view) = Modules::find($view, $this->_module, 'views/template/');

        if ($path != FALSE) {
            $this->_ci_view_paths = array($path => TRUE) + $this->_ci_view_paths;
            $view = $_view;
        }

        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
    }
```

Because I would like to be able to do this `$this->load->view('user/user_list', $data);` rather than `$this->load->view('template/user/user_list', $data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before. I wanted the "views" directory to come into the main public_html directory.

This is how I did it (Make a new file (MY_Loader.php), within the core directory inside the application folder);

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_ci_view_paths = array(FCPATH . 'views/' => TRUE);
        $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();
        $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
        $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
        $this->_ci_model_paths = array(APPPATH);

        log_message('debug', "MY_Loader Class Initialized");
    }       

}
```

Then, I could move the views folder, to anywhere I wanted (FCPATH . 'views/').

I would never recommend editing the system files. If you need to change anything, then simply extend the class.

Comment: Works fine now `$this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . 'views/template/' => TRUE);`